# Gradle fails to resolve a weird dependency from a detached configuration

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am using gradle to build several Eclipse plugins here:
https://travis-ci.org/JPL-IMCE/gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.core

This is the CI for this repo: 
https://github.com/JPL-IMCE/gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.core

I've been stumped by this dependency resolution failure:

```
./gradlew :gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui:build --stacktrace
:buildSrc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:copyMainKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestKotlin NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:copyTestKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
4 actionable tasks: 0 executed, 4 avoided 
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.model:generateXtext UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.model:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.model:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.model:classes UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.model:jar UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:generateXtextLanguage UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:generateXtext UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:classes UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl:jar UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ide:generateXtext UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ide:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ide:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ide:classes UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ide:jar UP-TO-DATE
:gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui:generateXtext FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui:detachedConfiguration2'.
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:1233.
  Required by:
      project :gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:1233.
      > Could not get resource 'http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6.3-201703010400/plugins/ivy_1233.xml'.
         > Could not GET 'http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6.3-201703010400/plugins/ivy_1233.xml'.
            > Connect to download.eclipse.org:80 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui:detachedConfiguration2'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:851)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:406)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.buildSnapshots(AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.<init>(AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesTaskStateChanges.<init>(InputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:177)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:85)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:244)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:223)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:250)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:1233.
Required by:
    project :gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:85)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:661)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:672)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:297)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$8.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:493)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$8.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:485)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:485)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1500(DefaultConfiguration.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:862)
        ... 95 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:1233.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:72)
        ... 117 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6.3-201703010400/plugins/ivy_1233.xml'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:178)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:458)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:320)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:99)
        ... 122 more
```

It is surprisingly painful to build eclipse plugins with gradle because resolving dependencies to Eclipse' p2 repositories is such a pain.

Since this project uses Xcore, Xtext, Xtend and EMF, I've had to add several Ivy repositories corresponding to Eclipse P2 repos.

There are also problems with some P2 artifacts whose dependencies include platform-specific variables. Fortunately, I managed to handle this with a substitution rule.

```
subprojects {

    ext.xtextVersion = '2.11.0'

    // see http://services.typefox.io/open-source/jenkins/job/xtext-eclipse/job/maintenance_2.11/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/p2-repository/plugins/
    ext.xtextUIVersion = '2.11.1.v20170201-1233'

    // see http://services.typefox.io/open-source/jenkins/job/xtext-xtend/job/maintenance_2.11/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/p2-repository/plugins/
    ext.xtendVersion = '2.11.1.v20170201-1447'

    // see http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6.3-201703010400/
    ext.emfVersion = '2.11.0.v20160420-0247'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        ivy {
            url "http://services.typefox.io/open-source/jenkins/job/xtext-xtend/job/maintenance_2.11/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/p2-repository/"
            layout "pattern", {
                artifact "plugins/[artifact]_[revision].[ext]"
            }
        }

        ivy {
            url "http://services.typefox.io/open-source/jenkins/job/xtext-eclipse/job/maintenance_2.11/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/p2-repository/"
            layout "pattern", {
                artifact "plugins/[artifact]_[revision].[ext]"
            }
        }

        // See versions here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/
        ivy {
            url "http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6.3-201703010400/"
            layout "pattern", {
                artifact "plugins/[artifact]_[revision].[ext]"
            }
        }

    }

    ...

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'asm'

        resolutionStrategy {
            dependencySubstitution {
                // Handle dependency on a variable.
                substitute module('org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}') with module("org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${System.getProperty('osgi.platform')}:3.+")

                substitute module('org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change:[2.5.0,)') with module("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change:${emfVersion}")
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that the dependency "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.ui:${xtextUIVersion}" (i.e.:
"org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.ui:2.11.1.v20170201-1233") somehow makes Gradle look for "org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:1233"

There is no such version.... 
I tried to work around this weird phenomenon with substitution & force rules, neither of which helped to correct this bogus dependency.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I attached a debugger to see what's going on...

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
./gradlew :gov.nasa.jpl.imce.oml.dsl.ui:build
```

Then I put a breakpoint on the DefaultExternalModuleDependency constructor. When the breakpoint hits with:

```
group: java.lang.String  = "org.eclipse.xtend"
name: java.lang.String  = "org.eclipse.xtend.core"
version: java.lang.String  = "1233"
```

I see that the stack trace implicates the Xtext gradle plugin:

```
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.<init>(DefaultExternalModuleDependency.java:29)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.<init>(DefaultExternalModuleDependency.java:25)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source:-1)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor47.newInstance(Unknown Source:-1)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.notations.DependencyStringNotationConverter.createDependencyFromString(DependencyStringNotationConverter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.notations.DependencyStringNotationConverter.convert(DependencyStringNotationConverter.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.notations.DependencyStringNotationConverter.convert(DependencyStringNotationConverter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.CharSequenceNotationConverter.convert(CharSequenceNotationConverter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.CompositeNotationConverter.convert(CompositeNotationConverter.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.NotationConverterToNotationParserAdapter.parseNotation(NotationConverterToNotationParserAdapter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.ErrorHandlingNotationParser.parseNotation(ErrorHandlingNotationParser.java:47)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultDependencyFactory.createDependency(DefaultDependencyFactory.java:45)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.create(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:95)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.create(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:90)
  at org.xtext.gradle.GradleExtensions.externalModule(GradleExtensions.xtend:10)
  at org.xtext.gradle.GradleExtensions.externalModule(GradleExtensions.xtend:16)
  at org.xtext.gradle.XtendLanguageBasePlugin$4$2.execute(XtendLanguageBasePlugin.java:163)
  at org.xtext.gradle.XtendLanguageBasePlugin$4$2.execute(XtendLanguageBasePlugin.java:157)
```

Looking at [XtendLanguageBasePlugin.automaticallyInferXtendCompilerClasspath](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/blob/master/xtext-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/xtext/gradle/XtendLanguageBasePlugin.xtend#L54) which uses a [regex version pattern matcher](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/blob/master/xtext-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/xtext/gradle/tasks/XtextExtension.xtend#L44), I see that the problem comes from that regex:

```
static val LIB_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("org\\.eclipse\\.xtext\\..*-(\\d.*?).jar")
```

When applied to "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.ui:2.11.1.v20170201-1233", it binds to the suffix, "1233".

At least, this explains where the bogus dependency comes from.